# Linux Kerberos and Ldap problems

Tags: linux, debian, active-directory, windows-domain, ldap

i am currently facing some problems with an Debian server which has joined our Active Directory.

The server sends out LDAP and Kerberos packages to multiple AD Controllers on different locations around the world in our Domain.

I want my Server to send these just to the AD Controller in our Location.

I tried to change the Krb5.conf but to no avail.

Do you have any tips for me?

Comment: What AD client software are you using?

Comment: I have installed Samba with winbind, Kerberos5 and PAM.